# Scroll issue over selectionlistener using ListModel

Tags: json, codenameone

In Codenameone, I've used the list as container renderer to form and after parsing JSON data using hastable, I shown results on items of the list. The list contains hastable has been passed over `ListModel` and it works fine . Whenever I use `ListModel` , I just want to click on list item and action triggers. Problem is using `ListModel` it has only

```
datalist.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

                public void selectionChanged(int oldSelected, int newSelected) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }
            });
```

I won't be able to scroll the whole page due to select on any item, it triggers the action.
Any option how I can scroll whole results on page as well `onClick` so that I can trigger the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use action listener in the List not the list model.

Comment: Absolutely rite. I just love the codenameone surely gonna develop more apps in it . I respect ur work.